# Can a daemon running under smf on SmartOs have a memory cap

Tags: smf, smartos

Can I set a memory limit on a daemon running under smf on Joyent SmartOS?

I have a logging process that seems to balloon after cpu time gets above 100. I only have small instances (512Mb), it would be great for it to restart the daemon when memory reaches a certain level?

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can try is to create a "project" for the process and then set a memory cap for that project.

http://www.princeton.edu/~unix/Solaris/troubleshoot/resmgmt.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1460/rm.rcapd-4.html